# Why movement of SVG object is so unpredictable?

Tags: jquery, svg, click, viewbox

I am trying to move an `SVG object` using `click()` method, but the object is not moving where I want it to move.

> I want my object to move exactly where user's screen was clicked!

Take a look at what I am trying :

```js
 $(function() {
    // alert("click somewhere on your screen");
    $(window).on("click", function(e) {
      var xco = e.pageX;
      var yco = e.pageY;
      $("circle").animate({
        "cx": xco,
        "cy": yco
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg viewBox="10 10 80 80" style="height:80vh; width:80vw; border:2vw solid black;">
    <circle cx="20" cy="10" r="5" fill="yellow" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates you are using are for the page. Inside an `svg`. First, you want the coordinates from the svg origin. In addition, you are setting an viewBox, which changes how those coordinates are interpreted. Fortunately, javascript provides a couple of functions and objects that can help. Mainly, you need to read about `getScreenCTM()`. Below is an example with a function that takes care of the transformation:

```js
function transformAbsPoint(x, y){
  var svg = $("#svgel")[0];
  var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = x;
  pt.y = y;
  var loc = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  return [loc.x, loc.y];
}

 $(function() {
    // alert("click somewhere on your screen");
    $(window).on("click", function(e) {
      var pt = transformAbsPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
      $("circle").animate({
        "cx": pt[0],
        "cy": pt[1]
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg id="svgel" viewBox="10 10 80 80" style="height:80vh; width:80vw; border:2vw solid black;">
    <circle cx="20" cy="10" r="5" fill="yellow" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```